# Powershell Error in deleting files and folders

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where the powershell script should be deleting the log files and log folders in a path, lets say they are under the path C:\MLA\logs.

Below is the script that I have been using, it completes removes the files but the problem is the script does not work for deleting the folders, the error it displays is something like could not find part of the path

C:\MLA\logs\ART_Daily.

below is the script

```
$root=C:\MLA\logs
$limit=(Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

get-childitem -Path $root -Recurse -force |
            where-Object {(($_.name -match 'Daily|ART|ABC|IIC') -or ($_.PSIsContainer -match 'Daily|ART|ABC|IIC')) -and ($_.CreationTime -lt $limit)} |Remove-Item -recurse -Force
```

The $*name checks for files ( if the names piped are part of the file name for any of the file ) in the root path and $*.PSIsContainer check for folders 9 f the names piped are part of the folder name for any of the folder ) inside the root path which is parametrized.

Can you help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your filter for starters:

```
$_.name -match 'Daily|ART|ABC|IIC'
```

will match files *and* folders with that name.

```
$_.PSIsContainer -match 'Daily|ART|ABC|IIC'
```

Will find nothing because the `PSIsContainer` property is boolean (is it a container or not: True/False?).

Comment: $_.PSIsContainer -match 'Daily|ART|ABC|IIC' -eq $True should it be something like this??

Comment: To find Files: `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false` or for folders `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true`. Of course you cannot get all files and folder this way: either / or.

Comment: On the whole you would be better off using the `-filter`, `-include` and `-exclude` parameters of Get-ChildItem anyway as they hand the filtering to the file system provider which is quicker.